# jquery fileupload widget

Tags: php, jquery-ui, jquery-file-upload

I am trying to use the jquery file upload widget. I have copied the demo code to my site. When it runs I get the following error (according to Firebug):

"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://24.xxx.xxx.xxx/server/php/"

The file I want to upload gets dumped into the files/ directory without issue. The httpd error log has no error listed. If I run the server/php/index.php directly from the browser I see a correctly formatted JSON string.

I have changed all the URLs to point to my site and not jqueryupload.appoint.com.

Any guidance would be appreciated. I am running Linux, Apache 2.4, PHP 5.4.10.

The post data is:

```
-----------------------------314262861723757 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[]"; filename="004.JPG" Content-Type: image/jpeg ÿØÿà�JFIF��H�H��ÿá&.Exif��MM�*�������

(lots of this)

$óîxÕéº4kq¡ÞÚj7¯i34à)13�Çn{ó^}­@·öåå[k+÷@Úã`ÿ�­MNYEÁSGÿÙ -----------------------------314262861723757--
```

The index.php code is:

```
<?php
/*
 * jQuery File Upload Plugin PHP Example 5.14
 * https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload
 *
 * Copyright 2010, Sebastian Tschan
 * https://blueimp.net
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license:
 * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 */
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
require('UploadHandler.php');
$upload_handler = new UploadHandler();
```

Uploadhandler.php is unmodified from the original supplied in the demo which is available here: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload#download

**EDIT: Additional information.**
I can upload non-image files without issue. It is only when uploading image files that a problem appears. The /server/php/thumbnails directory has read and write permissions and is owned by the daemon user. I see references in the code to file.thumbnail_url but no where do I see that variable defined in either the index.html program or the supporting javascript programs.

Comment: Have a look at the server logs to find out what exactly the error is about.

Comment: I did as I mentioned above. There is nothing in the error log. The access_log file only shows:  "POST /server/php/ HTTP/1.1" 500 -

Comment: As you are using Firebug...what does the POST request look like, which is executed by the widget? Anything odd in there? Seems to me like the server doesn't like the way the widget talks to it.

Comment: I edited my question to include the post data which looks normal for an image file. I think the post is okay because if I change the server/php/index.php program to just exit I get a different error such as "Empty File information". I am not familiar enough with the jquery.upload code to figure out what is perhaps misconfigured. I have traced the call to the error handling but I don't know why the error is being raised. Also, the file is uploaded and I can display it afterwards in the browser.

Comment: Well, then your target script is probably doing something weird. Give us a peek at that index.php that is causing the problem.

Comment: I modified the question to include the code.

Comment: In that case I would suggest that you ask the author for help. I - for one - will not read all that code trying to figure out what's happening. :)

Comment: Don't expect you to read it. Posted at your request. I was hoping someone who had experience with the plug-in would be able to help.

Comment: what does apache error log tells you?

Comment: The log has no errors. I have just fixed the problem. PHP was not compiled with GD.

Answer (score -2):

you need the GD library:

```
apt-get install php-gd
```